# Keras taking a series of ordered lists as input?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, opencv

I have a series of videos undergoing analysis. We have 50 videos, and we are sampling 10 frames per video for now. We run each frame through a model that outputs a list of length 7 (scores for various metrics). So we have an X of shape [numVideos x [numFrames x [7]]]. This output is in the same order it occurs in in the video.

Ideally we would train a model using this data, and the new model would output a single int score.

For example, the total input list is shape (50, 10, 7). Here is an example of one of the 50 video analyses:

```
[[2.10857585e-01 3.44210785e-05 7.68336877e-02 6.52071908e-02
   1.59574211e-01 6.07666420e-03 4.81416196e-01]

[1.25921518e-01 3.82323651e-06 9.80229899e-02 1.59665961e-02
   5.27808852e-02 7.20748529e-02 6.35229409e-01]

[1.96348786e-01 1.39075582e-05 3.05381954e-01 8.71435739e-03
   7.70738944e-02 3.36979516e-02 3.78769159e-01]

[4.88201588e-01 4.07423446e-04 1.31438121e-01 2.09173430e-02
   5.96358590e-02 2.17649899e-02 2.77634591e-01]

[2.23202184e-01 9.74372160e-05 1.74910247e-01 2.34939177e-02
   3.35233539e-01 6.30585337e-03 2.36756831e-01]

[6.06459320e-01 2.96085584e-03 1.29230097e-01 2.59685959e-03
   1.56335548e-01 6.93407189e-03 9.54832658e-02]

[2.97920138e-01 1.25984091e-03 1.89080209e-01 5.00026112e-03
   8.90274197e-02 6.42844364e-02 3.53427678e-01]

[3.03987801e-01 6.44640977e-06 1.16339259e-01 2.88505014e-03
   1.53694913e-01 6.00992441e-02 3.62987250e-01]

[1.29550800e-01 1.86390607e-04 9.91750583e-02 2.72049874e-01
   8.33113417e-02 2.60952320e-02 3.89631271e-01]

[1.64423732e-03 2.68871787e-07 3.26379202e-04 9.86126721e-01
   5.81838889e-04 1.44834805e-03 9.87217203e-03] ]
```

I'm having a bit of trouble with this part because I am new to Keras - is it possible to have Keras consider this data in order at the video level? Aka outputting a prediction on a single video using [numFrames x [7]]? I think we could make an alright model using the frames data in any order, but I believe the order of the frames (and the changes and rate of change between them) is valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic way is using recurrent layers. They are made for working with timesteps in sequence and learn from them.

So, if you make your `X` have shape `(50,10,7)`, as in `(videos, frames, features)`, you can create a model like this:

```
inputTensor = Input((10,7)) #also possible with (None,7) for variable frame counts   

#some recurrent layers with return_sequences=True
output = LSTM(someUnits, return_sequences=True)(inputTensor)
output = LSTM(aFewUnits, return_sequences=True)(output)
```

Now, if you want a score for each frame, keep the `return_sequences=True` and:

```
output = Dense(1, activation=someActivation)(output)
model = Model(inputTensor, output) #output shape = (50,10,1)
```

Or, if you want a total score for each video, the last recurrent layer should have `return_sequences=False`:

```
output = LSTM(aFewUnits, return_sequences=False)(output)
output = Dense(1, activation=someActivation)(output)
model = Model(inputTensor, output)   #output shape = (50,1)
```

---

Now, if your frames are actual images and you want to process these images, it gets a bit more complicated. You should consider the existence of the pixels and the shape of this data.

Supposing you have frames with 8 x 8 pixels, in RGB, your video input shape should be something like `(50,10,8,8,3)`.

One approach is to first reshape the image into features: `X.reshape((50,10,-1))`
And then concatenate the 7 features: `X = np.concatenate([X,features], axis=-1)`

And follow using that model.

Another approach is to use the [ConvLSTM2D](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d) layer, which takes inputs shaped as the original video. At some point in the model you collapse the spatial dimensions into features (the same reshape procedure above) and concatenate with a second input which would be the 7 features).

Comment: Hey Daniel - I know it's been a while but I had a question. For using (None,7) for variable frame counts, would all 50 videos need to have the same variable frame count, or could they all be different? For example, one video could have 100 frames and the next video could have 150?

Comment: They could be different, but you can't have them all in a single numpy array. So you will need to train each video individually.

Comment: Thanks so much! You've really helped me out. I'm guessing that also applies to validation_data in model.fit() ? Is there a best-practice way to measure val_loss when the validation data also has a nonuniform shaped size?

Comment: Hard question.... I think masking is the only way... but I don't understand exactly how it works or whether it applies to the loss function.